# How can I get my Private Keys of wax account?

Tags: keys, private-key

Account was created on wallet.wax.io
Can I somehow get my Private Keys?

Comment: How to get my private key in wax wallet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used the Wax Cloud Wallet to create your account you can't get your private keys. It's a custodial Service without the possibility to extract your private keys.

Comment: Is there a way to create a non-custodial account on wax?

Comment: @wlraider70 Anchor wallet supports WAX: https://greymass.com/en/anchor